Select column1 from table -> SQL Server does load all the table from disk to memory?
I have a question to know if SQL Server loads in memory all the table (including all the columns) when we do a query like
select column1 from table

If this table has many columns, is the whole table loaded into memory? Or is SQL Server just loading the pages with column1?
Thanks a lot!
I have been trying to know it using profiler but I don't see the number of bytes loaded from disk.

I removed the general, ISO/ANSI  tag, since this is a very SQL Server specific question.

Note that tables have columns, not fields.

Like so many other things in life, the answer is "it depends"

yes yes @jarlh, you are right... my mistake... column (y)

@flackoverstow, i would like get that the sql server just load in memory the required columns for all the records. Do you know how avoid load all the table with all the columns for the select "select column1 from table"?

The answer is ... "maybe". Why are you worried about this?

@topsail agreed. SQL server has  many years of remarkable optimizations under the hood. It simply doesn't matter, it's going to answer that query as quickly as it possibly can.

I am worry, because i have a lot of tables (498) with two columns varchar (2000), and there is one application that is doing select count(*) from every table. So,when these queries are executed we are seeing that the memory has been increased a lot because all the tables with all the columns are loaded in memory. For this reason I would like to know if is possible avoid this full loading. I have tried changing the select to "select count(id) from table" but happens the same. So, summarizing, the queries execution is quick (no problem in that) but we need to have more RAM than really necessary.

... and every table has near 300.000 records....

It won't be loading the tables into memory just to count them.

@DaleK, i thought that since 25 years ago :D... but seems yes. Seems that when there arent conditionals (without where) sql server is doing that.... but, maybe, is someway to avoid it. For this reason I ask it.

Check your execution plan, you'll see what its trying to do... maybe you are missing a proper index.

SQL Server needs the pages to be in the buffer pool (memory) before it can do anything with them. For the query select column1 from table it will be able to get that from the narrowest available index containing that column. If there are no such indexes then it will have no choice but to load the pages containing the base table rows into memory (if they aren't already in the buffer pool). This contains "something" for every column in the table though may just be a pointer to the data if it is stored off row rather than on the data page

To understand why it will potentially read everything (see @MartinSmith's comment for an accurate statement about it), I suggest watching Brent Ozar's excellent How to think like the SQL Server engine - it takes an hour or two (depending on version) but I think it's the best way, in a short amount of time, to get a good understanding of how data is stored and used in SQL Server, and why, in this case, you potentially need to read all the data in all the rows just to count them.

You can read from the sys.partitions view to get row counts, this should avoid most perf issues. But it doesn't do where
